# Android - Slide Menu like in Uber

Tags: android, menu

I am looking to implement a menu like used on the Android Uber app.

It seems to be like an action bar on top with 3 small settings stripes on left side.  (probably not a real action bar)
When clicking in that area a black menu slides out from the left and occupies 70% of the screen.
The right side of the screen still showing the map is darkened to keep focus on the menu.

I like that style, it looks good and everyone immediately knows how to use it.
I would like to have the same but don't know where to start or if there is maybe something available that would do something similar.

The actionbar itself only offers the menu on top right which is better for pure settings.
I also experimented with a split action bar having the menu items on bottom but that also seems superior to the clean interface Uber provides.

Comment: please provide a screen shot of what you are talking about

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Android Navigation Drawer. It's an Android sanctioned navigation pattern and more details about it can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). For some more technical documentation and an example of how to use it, you can find a sample over [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). It works great with the Action Bar so shouldn't need anything too custom outside of what the Android v4 compat library gives you.

Comment: awesome, I think that's exactly the same